# IOMEGA StorCenter discovery of IX2-200 after new computer re-installation

Tags: networking, router, nas

### Executive Summary:

I have an Iomega Ix2-200, probably first generation, purchased and installed in 2010.  After setting it up, I adapted it to my home network needs, and it has worked flawlessly since.

Recently, my computer died, and I bought a new one.  I restored everything from backups, and have been happy.  As to the install, I recovered everything except EMC/IOMEGA’s StorCenter management application.

So, I installed the StorCenter software from the original 2010 install disk.   It could not discover my device, and failed to get through the initial screens.  Furthermore, subsequent to the unsuccessful device discovery, my network has been extremely slow.  Any accesses to the NAS device are very slow with long hourglass waits for each access. (I am running Win7-64.)

Result: my NAS performance has degraded significantly, and I still do not have a management path to my device.

### Details of my network:

After initial installation, I had some issues accessing the NAS from some wireless laptops, so I reconfigured my router and the NAS device details so that the IX2-200 was on a fixed/reserved IP address.  This did solve that problem.  (That problem is in the past, and no longer relevant.)

Also, of potential note, I have 2 routers – a Verizon router, from my ISP provider, which connects to my “real” home network router (Netgear WNDR 3700).  This Netgear router has an IP address of 10.0.0.01.  My computer is a dynamic IP address, (right now it is 10.0.0.14).  The IOMEGA IX2-200 is a fixed reserved IP address of 10.0.0.9. The subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.  DHCP address start at 10.0.0.2.

The IP of the Verizon router is 192.168.1.1.  The Netgear router is shown as 192.168.1.2.

### Wild guess:

I wonder if the fixed IP address is the culprit, and my install of the StorCenter software has somehow mucked up the settings inside the IX2-200, thus resulting in the now-awful performance.  Of course, I can delete the reserved IP address for the NAS device in my Netgear router, but I am worried of making a bad situation even worse.

I apologize for the verbosity; I am hoping to give as much information as necessary to help.  I am expecting the answer might be quite simple, and I am thankful, in advance, of any assistance or suggestions.

Larry

Comment: Update: power cycling the NAS device seems to have fixed everything.  Also, I updated to the newest more modern version of the Storage Manager.